# OpenCL doesn't allowes late initializtion of variable in constant space

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I want to generate a matrix which will be read by many thread after its generation so I declared it with program scope. It has to be constant so I am just assigning values once so

1) why openCl asking for initialization while declaration only?

2) How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Because you can't tell the gpu which elements are written by which threads. Constants are prepared by preprocessor using scalar engine, not parallel one. Parallel engine would need N x N times synchronizations to achieve that, where N is number of threads participating in building constant buffer.

2-a) If you want to work with constant memory, prepare a simple(__global, not constant) buffer in a kernel, use it as constant buffer in the next kernel(engine puts it in constant memory space). But constant space is small so the matrix should be small. This needs 2 kernels, means kernel overhead.

2-b) If cache performance is enough, just use a buffer. So it can be in a single kernel(first thread group prepares matrix, remaining ones compute using it, not starting until first group gives signal using atomic functions)

2-c) If local memory is bigger than constant memory, you can use local memory and build that matrix for each compute unit by themselves so it should take same amount of cycles(maybe even less if you use all cores) and probably faster than constant memory. This doesn't need communication between thread groups so would be fast.

2-d)If matrix is big and you need most of bandwidth, distribute it to all memory spaces. Example: put 1/4 of matrix to constant memory (5x bandwidth), put 1/4 of matrix to local memory (10x bandwidth), put 1/4 of matrix to global memory(2x from cache performance), put remaining data to instruction space(instructions themselves) so multiple threads would be working on 4 different places concurrently, using all bandwidth (constant + local + cache + instruction cache).